# Find sibling records that have differences in M2M items

Tags: django

I need to find objects that have differences in `Tags` among two children (sibling models).

Example setup:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
   pass

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)

class Child_OLD(models.Models):
    parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent, ...)
    tags = models.Many2ManyField(Tag)

class Child_NEW(models.Models):
    parent = models.ForiegnKey(Parent, ...)
    tags = models.Many2ManyField(Tag)
```

I want to make sure all `Tags` records on Child_OLD are represented on the `Child_NEW` record.  Specifically, I'd like to find any parent where Child_OLD has tags that Child_NEW does not have, using a faster method than checking each one individually.

I am only interested in finding parents where the child_old has a tag that is not on child_new.
Here is a loop that accomplishes a similar thing:

```
diffs = []
for parent in parents:
    cn_tags = Tag.objects.filter(child_new__parent=parent)
    qs_diff = parent.child_old.tags.all().difference(cn_tags)

    if qs.exists():
        diffs.append(parent.pk)
```

Again, I'm looking to do this with a queryset, in a more optimized fashion as iterating through each parent is very slow

There are ~100mil+ "parents" and ~500 unique tags. A typical child will have 0-5 tags

Comment: Does your definition of "different" only include tags missing from `Child_NEW` or also tags that are *only* in `Child_NEW`?

Comment: There's something confusing in your current formulation: `parent.child_old` makes it look like the child to parent relationship is one-to-one, but a `ForeignKey` is a many-to-one relation.  This is important because your `cn_tags` has a different meaning if a parent can have only one child...

Comment: Old is one to one but new is an FK (it’s actually part of a generic foreign key + generic relationship in the real code)

Comment: @EndreBoth only missing tags from new. Tags may have been added to new

Comment: You mentioned 100 million parent records. How many different tags are we talking about?

Comment: around 500 different tags

Comment: Any progress made?

Comment: Got caught up in other things, I need to go through your answer, understand it and test it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to filter the tags in `Child_NEW` that are identical to the tags in `Child_OLD` and check if their count is identical to the count of all tags in `Child_NEW`.

First, the innermost subquery to select matching tags in `Child_OLD`:

```
criteria_sq = (Child_OLD.objects
    .filter(parent=OuterRef(OuterRef('id')))
    .values('tags__id')
)
```

This subquery is then wrapped in another subquery to count matching tags in `Child_NEW`:

```
select_sq = (Child_NEW.objects
    .filter(id=OuterRef('child_old__id'), tags__id__in=Subquery(criteria_sq, ))
    .values('parent')
    .annotate(tag_cnt=Count('parent'))
    .values('tag_cnt')
)
```

And here's the final queryset. There can be duplicate `Parents` if more than one `Child_NEW` refers to one `Parent`.

```
qs = (Parent.objects
    .annotate(tag_count_old=Count('child_old__tags'))
    .annotate(tag_count_new=Subquery(select_sq, output_field=IntegerField()))
    .filter(Q(tag_count_old__gt=F('tag_count_new')) | Q(tag_count_old__isnull=False, tag_count_new__isnull=True))
)
```

---

An alternative solution would be to use raw SQL to create a left join between the old child/tags intermediate table and the new child/tags intermediate table and to select parents that have null values on the right-hand side. On each side of this join, you would need further inner joins to a) respective child table and b) the parent table so that you can join on the parent table id.